# How to fetch data from table appending various queries in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to append various different queries for my filter but the problem here is my `orWhere` condition is working abnormally and giving me results irrespective of my where condition.

I'm adding my controller below:

```
public function earringsFilter(Request $request)
{
    if($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $data = array_filter($request->all());
        $filter = $data['filter'];
        $jewelleryEarringsData = Jwellery::select('id','name','price','msrp','metal_type','image_url','total_weight','image_2','image_3');
        $earrings = &$jewelleryEarringsData;
        $carat = array();
        $amount = array();
        $metal = array();
        if(isset($data['metal'])){
            $metal = $data['metal'];
            //$earrings->whereIn('metal_type', $metal);
            foreach($metal as $valk){
                $earrings->orWhere('metal_type', 'like', '%'.$valk.'%');
            }
        }
        if(isset($data['amount']['1']) && $data['amount']['1'] !=''){
            $amount = $data['amount'];
            $amt1 = $amount['0'];
            $amt2 = $amount['1'];
            $earrings->whereBetween('price',[$amt1,$amt2]);
        }
        if(isset($data['carat']['1']) && $data['carat']['1'] !=''){
            $carat = $data['carat'];
            $carat1 = $carat['0'];
            $carat2 = $carat['1'];
            $earrings->where('total_weight','>=',$carat1)->where('total_weight','<=',$carat2);
        } 
        $jewelleryEarringsData = $earrings->where('item_type', $filter)->get();
    }
}
```

So the code where I'm using `orWhere` function of Laravel is giving me abnormal results.

Comment: also post the table structure,data and desired otuput

Comment: you are not assigning the values back to earring variable

Answer (score 2):

Please Change your

```
$jewelleryEarringsData = Jwellery::select('id','name','price','msrp','metal_type','image_url','total_weight','image_2','image_3');
```

To

```
$jewelleryEarringsData = Jwellery::select('id','name','price','msrp','metal_type','image_url','total_weight','image_2','image_3')->get();
```

And also re-assign values back to earring variables.
Hope this helps you

Comment: yeah... even I had same doubt

Comment: thanks for replying but the problem is there with the orWhere condition .If i remove orWhere the above appended query is working absolutely fine.but if i add orWhere the above query is working irrespective of where condition

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
foreach ($metal as $valk){
    $earrings = $earrings->orWhere('metal_type', 'like', '%'.$valk.'%');
}
```